# what is the difference between postman collections and API documentation?

Tags: rest, postman, postman-collection, api-documentation

I have postman collections of some rest apis that I delivered to someone who want to do a secure assessment on them, however he asked for full API documentation, and I'm not very familiar with rest APIs, so what is the difference? ain't postman collections are API documentation at the same time ?

Answer (score 1):

a bit late perhaps, but a postman collection is in a way showing the customer what API endpoints there are, and how to use them, but I think the customer was referring to some documentation like: https://www.openapis.org/ or https://swagger.io/ Then you create a yaml file according to the specified format, and it will result in a documentation page like this: https://petstore.swagger.io/